# Checking if CRON script already running

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I am trying to write a script that needs to be run by cron. But because the script depends on some hardware components (can take variable time to execute or even hang), I need to make sure it's not already running to prevent it from piling in memory.

Script name is `fan_control.sh`, `cron` is a parameter. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
ps aux | grep -w "fan_control.sh cron" | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

This line returns number of instances running, if it's `> 1` then I have to exit. It works exactly as intended. However, to use it, I need to capture output to a variable. I tried both `...` and $(...) methods and was surprised to find out that it would return `+1` compared to actual number if instances running. Not understanding what was happening, I just decided to live with it and use `> 2` for comparison. Looked like it worked.

However, when I tried running the script via cron, I found out it was returning `+2` compared to what I was expecting. If I remove `wc -l` from the command line, I can actually see extra instances listed (with different PIDs).

UPDATE:

So i've tried what was suggested, here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "cron" ]; then

COUNT_RUNNING=$(pgrep -fc "fan_control.sh cron")
if [[ $COUNT_RUNNING > 1 ]]; then
date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
echo "Too many instances running ($COUNT_RUNNING), exit."
exit;
fi
fi

[main script contents]
```

This seems to work fine if called from command line. I've tried calling it simultaneously from two shell windows and I can actually see the message "Too many instances running (2), exit." Now, I add a cron job:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/user90/fan_control.sh cron > /home/user/cronlog.txt
```

And cronlog.txt contents is:

```
2018-03-18 22:20:01
Too many instances running (2), exit.
2018-03-18 22:21:01
Too many instances running (2), exit.
2018-03-18 22:22:01
Too many instances running (2), exit.
```

So, I've gotten rid of extra process spawned when capturing command output to variable, however, CRON still spawns an extra process. I'm just curious why it's happening?

Comment: Sounds like essentially the same issue as here: [Generic solution to prevent a long cron job from running in parallel?](//askubuntu.com/q/142002) i.e. `cron` is spawning a shell command that is also matching your `grep` pattern

Comment: We can't help unless you show us the cron line that's calling the script, and the mechanism you use to check the output of that command. There's no reason to capture anything in a variable. That's the wrong command, by the way, you just want `pgrep -fc "fan_control.sh cron"`.  But check the answers of the dupe steeldriver suggested.

Comment: Apologies, the previous question I intended to link was [Running pgrep in a crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014559/running-pgrep-in-a-crontab)

Comment: @steeldriver that was my bad, not yours. You had originally linked to [Running pgrep in a crontab](//askubuntu.com/q/1014559), but since that has no answers and is closed as a duplicate of [Generic solution to prevent a long cron job from running in parallel?](//askubuntu.com/q/142002), I edited your comment to point the OP directly to the answers instead of pointing them to a unanswered, closed dupe. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @terdon ah that makes sense - I thought I was suffering from posting-before-coffee syndrome again. IIRC none of the answers to  the marked dupe actually explain *why* the `grep` / `pgrep` counts an extra process though.

Comment: No, which is why I didn't just close as a dupe :P

Comment: Actually, the problem IS extra processes being spawned. One extra process is spawned when capturing output to variable, another one if same is called as a cron task. I'll update the question now.

Comment: Just use `run-one` or `solo`. Matching the process exactly via pgrep is tricky if you have to use `-f`, unless you have a PID file and then the complexity of ensuring a correct PID file makes the special tools worth it.

Comment: As for the extra process, that is trivial: cron runs `sh  -c '/usr/local/user90/fan_control.sh cron > /home/user/cronlog.txt'`, and `pgrep -f "fan_control.sh cron"` will of course match that `sh` process.

Comment: Muru, I know all about run-one, there's just gotta be an answer.  As for your answer, how is running via cron different from running via command line? Number of process reported when running via cron is +1 compared to that when run from command line.